# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when i try to print value

Tags: php, foreach

This is my array

```
[
    'field_test1' => [
        'field_test2' => [ 'value' => 'Yes' ,'action' => 'visible']
    ],
    'field_test3' => [
        'field_test4' => [ 'value' => '2' ,'action' => 'visible']
    ]
    'body' => [
        'field_test2' => [ 'value' => 'No', 'action' => 'visible']
        'field_test4' => [ 'value' => '1', 'action' => 'visible']
    ]
]
```

When i try to loop through each element i am getting error like invalid argument passed for foreach;
My code is

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

what should i do??

Comment: Do you have a problem with commas? Arrays need comma seperators if you want the array to be valid. Thats not a valid array definintion, therefore not a valid array, therefore you get the error `Invalid argument supplied`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the comma after your second array within your array. Before the one with the 'body' key. Try using a decent IDE like PhpStorm, it will highlight the errors in your syntax for you, making the search for common errors easy.

```
$myArray =
   [
     'field_test1' => [
       'field_test2' => [ 'value' => 'Yes' ,'action' => 'visible']
     ],
     'field_test3' => [
       'field_test4' => [ 'value' => '2' ,'action' => 'visible']
     ],
     'body' => [
       'field_test2' => [ 'value' => 'No', 'action' => 'visible']
       'field_test4' => [ 'value' => '1', 'action' => 'visible']
     ],
  ];
```